DynamoDB - BatchGetItem - The provided key element does not match the schema
I am getting a "The provided key element does not match the schema" and I don't quite understand why.
I am using command the command below. I am trying to use a wildcard (*), but even when I use a specific id, it does not work.
aws dynamodb batch-get-item --request-items "{\"my-table\":{\"Keys\":[{\"Id\":{\"S\":\"*\"}}],\"ConsistentRead\":true,\"ProjectionExpression\":\"Id, TimeToLive\"}}"
The id column of the table is called 'Id'.
Looking at the doc, I don't see what I am doing wrong.
Also, just to let you guys know, my goal is to delete every row where TimeToLive is null/empty.

Does the TimeToLive attribute actually exist in the items to be deleted with some value (what value exactly?) or is the attribute absent?

TimeToLive does not exist in the rows I wish to delete.  It is the only thing that set them apart from those I do not wish to delete.

You can't use a Wildcard with BatchGetItem, you must use the full primary key for each item.
What you need to use is Scan with a FilterExpression.
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name my-table \
--filter-expression "attribute_not_exists('ttl')" \
--projection-expression "Id"

